# Run or start background worker more than one time in a form application

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I want to run my background worker again when it is complete..
That's like

backgroundWorker1.do work
then
background worker complete
then run background worker1.do work again...
How to do it..
Note that I have to run many background worker again and again....
Thank you

Comment: Why not run a loop inside 1 Bgw?

Comment: Have you tried just running the worker again? I believe it should work, or did you run into trouble?

Comment: I agree with @HenkHolterman using while(true) and using CancelAsync() will be a better approach

Answer (score 1):

You could add a call to `RunWorkerAsync()` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler

```
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((BackgroundWorker)sender).RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could just create a new Backgroundworker with the same Properties or you just call backgroundworker1.doWork() as it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

If your're using .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5 you can use [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) instead of BackgroundWorker:

```
// Here your long running operation
private int LongRunningOperation()
{
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   return 42;
}

// This operation will be called for processing tasks results
private void ProcessTaskResults(Task t)
{
   // We'll call this method in UI thread, so Invoke/BeginInvoke
   // is not required
   this.textBox.Text = t.Result;

}

// Starting long running operation
private void StartAsyncOperation()
{
   // Starting long running operation using Task.Factory
   // instead of background worker.
   var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(LongRunningOperation);   

   // Subscribing to tasks continuation that calls
   // when our long running operation finished
   task.ContinueWith(t =>
   {
      ProcessTaskResults(t);
      StartOperation();
   // Marking to execute this continuation in the UI thread!
   }, TaskScheduler.FromSynchronizationContext);
}

// somewhere inside you form's code, like btn_Click:
StartAsyncOperation();
```

Task-based asynchrony is a better way when dealing with long running operations.

Comment: AFAIK by default tasks will be created as short-term tasks. You should use `Task.Factory.StartNew(LongRunningOperation, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)` to give a hint to `Task` processing code.

Comment: @ony: Actually, BackgroundWorker class itself uses Thread Pool threads, so suggestion to use TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning breaks code behavior. The rule of thumb is to use LongRunning hint only when you definitely know that this operation is long running.